# Why does the visibility of m method change the output in this way? I expected the opposite to occur

Tags: java, methods, visibility, private, lookup

Title edit: "my* method" So the root of the problem is the method pmA3. It is present both in class A and in class B. Method lookup would suggest that when pmA3 gets called, it would look for the method in class B and execute that before it looks for the method in class A. Changing to public gives the expected result, but I have no idea why. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B bVar = new B();
        bVar.mA1();
        bVar.mA2();
    }
}
class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    private void pmA3() {
        System.out.println("pmA3 - A");
    }
    public void mA1() {
        System.out.println("mA1 - A");

    }
    public void mA2() {
        System.out.println("mA2 - A");
        pmA3();
    }


}
class B extends  A {
    public void pmA3() {
        System.out.println("pmA3 - B");
    }
    public void mA1() {
        System.out.println("mA1 - B");
    }
    public void mB1() {
        System.out.println("mB1 - B");
    }
}
```

```
Expected Results:

A
mA1 - B
mA2 - A
pmA3 - B

Actual Results:

A
mA1 - B
mA2 - A
pmA3 - A
```

Comment: what do you mean by "changing to public" ? you do not show a case where it's not public... How can you get this result since you never call `pmA3()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JLS §8.4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) explains that private methods are not inherited.

In fact, the call to `pmA3()` in your class `A` is *statically* bound. I.e. it is resolved at *compile time*. As the call is inside class `A` it will call the method `A#pmA3`.

When you declare the method as public, the above mentioned JLS paragraph tells you, that it is now inheritable.

As a consequence, the call to `pmA3()` in your class `A` is now *dynamically* bound. I.e. the compiler does not resolve the concrete method to call but delegates it to the *run time*. At runtime, the JVM looks for the concrete type of object on which the method is called and whether that type has an overridden method. In your case it is, so the method `B#pmA3` will be called.